# Concatenating .mtx files and changing counter for cell IDs

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have several files that look like this, where the header is the count of unique values per column.

[image]

How can I read several of these files and concatenate them all in one??
When I concatenate, I need that all the values in the column in the middle ADD the total value of count of that column from the file before, to continue with the count when I concatenate. The other two columns I don't mind.

My try:

```
matrixFiles = glob.glob(filesPath +'/*matrix.mtx')

dfs = []

i = 0

for file in sorted(matrixFiles):

    matrix = pd.read_csv(file, sep = ' ')
    cellNumber = matrix.columns[1]
    cellNumberInt = np.int64(cellNumber)

    if i > 0:

        matrix.iloc[:,1] = matrix.iloc[:,1] + cellNumberInt

    dfs.append(matrix)


    i = i + 1

big_file = pd.concat (dfs)
```

### I don't know how to access to cellNumberInt from the file iterated before to add it to the new one.

### When I concat dfs the output is not a three column dataframe. How can I concatenate all the files in the same columns and avoiding the header?

Comment: Not totally sure what you're trying to do here. Can you add some more input examples and the expected output? In my answer below, the 10474 number is the sum of all the middle column header numbers.  If you need to keep other rows, I can adjust my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1.csv:
33694,1298,2465341
33665,1299,20
33663,1299,8

2.csv:
53694,1398,3465341
33665,1399,20
33663,1399,8

3.csv:
13694,7778,3465341
44432,7780,20
33663,7780,8

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

matrixFiles = ['1.csv', '2.csv', '3.csv']

dfs = []
matrix_list = []
#this dict stores the i number (keys) and the cellNumberInt (values)
cellNumberInt_dict = {}

i = 0

for file in sorted(matrixFiles):

    matrix = pd.read_csv(file)
    cellNumber = matrix.columns[1]
    cellNumberInt = np.int64(cellNumber)

    cellNumberInt_dict[i] = cellNumberInt

    if i > 0:  
        matrix.rename(columns={str(cellNumberInt) : cellNumberInt + cellNumberInt_dict[i-1]}, inplace=True)

        dfs.append(matrix)

    if i < len(matrixFiles)-1:
        #we only want to keep the df values here, keeping the columns that don't
        # have shared names messes up the pd.concat()
        matrix_list.append(matrix.values)

    i += 1
# get the last df in the dfs list because it has the last cellNumberInt
last_df = dfs[-1]

#concat all of the values from the dfs except for the last one
arrs = np.concatenate(matrix_list)

#make a df from the numpy arrays
new_df = pd.DataFrame(arrs, columns=last_df.columns.tolist())

big_file = pd.concat([last_df, new_df])
big_file.rename(columns={big_file.columns.tolist()[1] : sum(cellNumberInt_dict.values())}, inplace=True)
print (big_file)



13694   10474   3465341
0   44432   7780    20
1   33663   7780    8
0   33665   1299    20
1   33663   1299    8
2   33665   1399    20
3   33663   1399    8
```